# VS 2019 navigate with the mouse

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Can I change the shortcut for jumping into implementation from an interface using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>left mouse button</kbd>. It feels more convenient navigating with the mouse.